# Failing Compile Automation with Pandoc and Travis

Tags: bash, github, markdown, travis-ci, pandoc

I am trying to automate compilation of Markdown with Pandoc and Travis through Github (while publishing the resulting HTML and Pdf files on Github Pages) without much success.

Followed this [guide](http://mgreau.com/posts/2016/03/28/asciidoc-to-gh-pages-with-travis-ci-docker-asciidoctor.html#travis_configuration_file) (which attempts the same but with Asciidoc and Asciidoctor). Using Docker image [jagregory/pandoc](https://hub.docker.com/r/jagregory/pandoc/) (currently uses Pandoc's version 1.19.2.1) and adapted the `script` lines on the `Yaml` file. Tried several scripts and until far had little if no success. As I write my `Yaml` file is as follows:

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker                  

before_install:            
  - mkdir -p output
  - docker pull jagregory/pandoc

script:
  - docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/documents/ --name pandoc-to-html jagregory/pandoc -v --standalone --toc --filter=pandoc-citeproc --data-dir=/documents/output body.md -o uwa.html
  - docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/documents/ --name pandoc-to-pdf jagregory/pandoc --standalone  --latex-engine=xelatex --filter=pandoc-citeproc --data-dir=/documents/output body.md -o uwa.pdf

after_error: 
  - docker logs pandoc-to-html
  - docker logs pandoc-to-pdf

after_failure:
  - docker logs pandoc-to-html
  - docker logs pandoc-to-pdf

after_success:      
  - cd output ; mv README.html index.html ; cp -R ../images images
  - git init
  - git config user.name "${GH_USER_NAME}"
  - git config user.email "{GH_USER_EMAIL}"
  - git add . ; git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages"
  - git push --force --quiet "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" master:gh-pages > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I get the following on the command line:

[image]

It obviously doesn't find the file `body.md` and I am sure the issue is pretty simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The README of the [jagregory/pandoc-docker](https://github.com/jagregory/pandoc-docker) project states that pandoc is run in the `/source` directory. It seems that replacing `/documents/` with `/source` in the volume specification should be enough.

Comment: There also seems to be a typo (missing `$`) in the git email config command.

Comment: @tarleb that was it, thanks! For some reason, nothing is being pushed to the `gh-pages` branch yet but the build passed. Changing the directory to `/source` did the trick. Should have read the readme file on the jagregory docker image... Also, many thanks for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got a passed build in Travis thanks to @tarleb suggestions above. After tweaking around with the script, I also managed to push to Github.

Here's my current `.travis.yml` configuration:

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker                  

before_install:            
  - mkdir -p output
  - docker pull jagregory/pandoc

script:
  - OUT=output; for FILE in *.md; do NAME=$(printf '%s\n' "$FILE" | cut -f 1 -d '.'); if [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme$ ]] && RDME=readme; [[ "$NAME" =~ ^README$ ]] && RDME=README; echo -e "\\e[34mThere's a \\e[33m$RDME \\e[34mfile. Good."; fi; echo -e "\\e[34mStart compiling..."; if ! [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $NAME.pdf..." && docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/source jagregory/pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t latex -o "$OUT/$NAME.pdf" && echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $NAME.html..." && docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/source jagregory/pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t html5 -o "$OUT/$NAME.html"; fi; if [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $RDME.html..." && docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/source jagregory/pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t html5 -o $OUT/$RDME.html; fi; done; echo -e "\\e[32mDone compiling!"; if [ -f "$RDME".md ]; then echo -e "\\e[34mCopying $RDME.md to /$OUT..." && cp "$RDME".md $OUT && echo -e "\\e[32mDone copying!"; elif ! [ -f "$RDME".md ]; then echo -e "\\e[31mThere's no readme.md to copy!"; fi; if [ -f "$OUT/$RDME".html ]; then echo -e "\\e[34mRenaming $RDME.html to index.html..." && mv "$OUT/$RDME".html $OUT/index.html && echo -e "\\e[32mAll tidy!"; else echo -e "\\e[31mThere's no readme.html to rename!"; fi;

after_success:      
  - cd output
  - git init
  - git config user.name "${GH_USER_NAME}" 
  - git config user.email "${GH_USER_EMAIL}" 
  - git add .
  - git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages"
  - git push -f -q "https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${GH_REF}" master:gh-pages
```

Here's the bash script above:

```
OUT=output
for FILE in *.md; do
    NAME=$(printf '%s\n' "$FILE" | cut -f 1 -d '.');
    if [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then
        [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme$ ]] && RDME=readme;
        [[ "$NAME" =~ ^README$ ]] && RDME=README;
    echo -e "\\e[34mThere's a \\e[33m$RDME \\e[34mfile. Good.";
    fi;
echo -e "\\e[34mStart compiling...";
if ! [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then
    echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $NAME.pdf..." &&
    pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t latex -o "$OUT/$NAME.pdf" &&
    echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $NAME.html..." &&
    pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t html5 -o "$OUT/$NAME.html";
fi;
if [[ "$NAME" =~ ^readme|README$ ]]; then
    echo -e "\\e[34mCompiling $RDME.html..." &&
    pandoc -f markdown "$FILE" -t html5 -o $OUT/$RDME.html;
fi;
done;
echo -e "\\e[32mDone compiling!";
if [ -f "$RDME".md ]; then
    echo -e "\\e[34mCopying $RDME.md to /$OUT..." &&
    cp "$RDME".md $OUT &&
    echo -e "\\e[32mDone copying!";
elif ! [ -f "$RDME".md ]; then
    echo -e "\\e[31mThere's no readme.md to copy!";
fi;
if [ -f "$OUT/$RDME".html ]; then
    echo -e "\\e[34mRenaming $RDME.html to index.html..." &&
    mv "$OUT/$RDME".html $OUT/index.html &&
    echo -e "\\e[32mAll tidy!";
else
    echo -e "\\e[31mThere's no readme.html to rename!";
fi;
```

Here's the job log:
[image]

What this script basically does is it compiles every Markdown file in `/source` into pdf and HTML, and then moves them to `/source/output`. The only exception is the readme.md file, which is compiled to HTML only, renamed to index.html and copied to `/source/output`.

A couple of things to pay attention to is to correctly type the output path in the script block (`output/foo.pdf`) and the URL of the repository where to push to (`"https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${GH_REF}"`).

Last but not least, not only the source where the repository will be published from needs to be set correctly but the default branch needs to be changed too, from `master` to `gh-pages`. To do both, navigate to `Settings` on the repository's page, then `Options-->GitHub Pages-->Source`, then select `gh-branch pages` from the dropdown menu (the ´gh-pages´ branch needs to have been created first for this option to appear). Finally, navigate to `Settings-->Branches-->Default Branch` and select `gh-branch` from the dropdown menu again.

The environment variables also need to be [set correctly in Travis](http://mgreau.com/posts/2016/03/28/asciidoc-to-gh-pages-with-travis-ci-docker-asciidoctor.html#_travis_ci_configuration).